# error 'cannot find module' on 'main.scss' with Webpack, SASS, and React

Tags: reactjs, sass, webpack, webpack-dev-server, sass-loader

When trying to set up SCSS to run the styling on my React application using Webpack I am presented with the error:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'style' in '/Users/sachinkaria/Workspace/GC' @ ./app/index.js 4:0-29 @ multi ./app/index.js'
```

and in the browser:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "/styles/main.scss"
```

My webpack.config.js configuration is below:

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');-
var HTMLWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: __dirname + '/app/index.html',
  filename: 'index.html',
  inject: 'body'
});

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './app/index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    filename: "index_bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "babel-loader"},{
            test: /\.scss$/,
            loaders: ['style', 'css', 'sass']
        }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [HTMLWebpackPluginConfig]
};
```

My package.json:

```
    {
  "name": "get-cooked",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server",
    "prod": "webpack -p"
  },
  "author": "Sachin Karia",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "classnames": "^2.2.5",
    "react": "^0.14.6",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.30.7",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.6",
    "react-router": "^2.0.0-rc5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.4.5",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.7.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.0",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.2",
    "webpack": "2.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  }
}
```

My index.js where I am importing the main.scss (producing the error):

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var routes = require('./config/routes');
require('./styles/main.scss');

ReactDOM.render(routes, document.getElementById('app'));
```

All my scss files are in my styles folder, however, I can't seem to import them into my index.js and am returned with the 'Cannot find module' error.'

Here is my folder structure:

```
- app
  - components
    - Home.js
  - config
    - routes.js
  - containers
  - styles
    - components
    - main.scss
  - index.html
  - index.js
- nodemodules
webpack.config.js
package.json
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out this is is a loader issue and not having the correct node modules. Simply running the script below will the issue:

```
npm install style-loader css-loader --save-dev
```

as well as using adding "style-loader", "css-loader" and "sass-loader" to Webpack rather than "style","css","sass".

Answer (score 3):

Replace `/styles` with

```
./styles
```

if `index.js` and `styles` are in the same folder

EDIT: If you're coming from Google - turns out `style-loader` and `css-loader` were not installed, make sure of that as well.

Comment: I've added the ./styles however still experience the same error. The index.js and styles are in the same folder.

Comment: So it now reads: require('./styles/main.scss')? What's the error now?

Comment: Yes, its the same error in the console: 'Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'style' in '/Users/sachinkaria/Workspace/GC'
 @ ./app/index.js 4:0-29
 @ multi ./app/index.js' and in my browser console: Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "./styles/main.scss"
    at webpackMissingModule

Comment: Well I'm stumped. Any chance of updating the question with your folder and paths?

Comment: This turned out to be a loaders issue, style-loader and css-loader were not installed.

Answer (score 2):

`/styles/main.scss` is an absolute path, so it will look in the root of your file system. You want to use a relative path:

```
require('./styles/main.scss');
```

This requires `styles` to be in the same directory as `index.js`. So if your project structure looks like:

```
- styles/
  - main.scss
- app/
  - index.js
```

You would need to go up one directory:

```
require('../styles/main.scss');
```

In case you would like to use paths relative to your project's root directory, you could use the [resolve](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/) options in your webpack config.

Comment: My index.js file is in the same directory as my styles folder. I have added the ./styles however still encounter the same error.

Answer (score 0):

This is majorly a webpack related issue and can appear on any webpack related app
Simply include `"css-loader": "^0.28.6", "style-loader": "^0.18.2"` in your package.json `"devDependencies": {...}` file and run `npm update`.

Answer (score 0):

I was playing about with CI and Automation in VSTS for ReactJS and auto deploy to SharePoint Online Web Parts made me update VS Code IDE, edit Gulp file, CD,MK's... etc. Upon re opening VS Code I didn't notice I am now in a diff Dir as shown in my Terminal window. What's worse? I am in a different directory which is not near my root node_modules folder! I was here initially: `../node_modules/ - << This is my initial Node mod root!!!`

```
../src/webparts/az
```

Whereas now I was in:

```
../node_modules/
../src/webparts\SPWPTest\src\webparts\az
```

NOTE: **before proceeding note down you node,IDE,react,ES, modules versions etc. in case you need a roll back.**

**Solution?**

1. CD to correct Dir
2. Do your `Cleans` and `Builds` to hopefully get `Served`. Gulp those.
3. If still not working then from within the new dir run a: `npm update`

Now you will node_modules have been added locally. Good or bad? I don't know but it works! :-)